# What kind of information should I store on the device, versus requesting via the web?

Tags: android, database, rest, client-server

I am developing an Android application, and I am making many RESTful requests to a server for information. Should I always make these requests, or store some of it in a SQLite database on the device? If I should store, how do I determine how much (if not all) of the data should be stored?

The app is something of an educational social network, so there are objects such as:

- Users
- Schools
- Notes
- Courses

  - Comments
  - Question

Currently the plan is to store the information in the database and check for updates frequently, or should I always request the data from the server? Additionally, should I pull nested data in a single request or split it up into multiple RESTful requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be to store **all** the data you have locally, and just sometimes fire up `AsyncTask` or `AsyncLoader` to download the updates. This way your users will be able to use your application when offline and don't need to wait for download to finish when your application starts.

You should **always** have some data to show. It might be useful to include a basic data set along with your application, so the database gets populated on the first run even when there's no network.

```
regarding single vs multiple requests:
```

single request is generally faster than several smaller requests, however, it has higher probability of failing on mobile networks. if your data requests don't take more than 10sec on GSM network, you should be fine, otherwise you might consider splitting into smaller requests.

Comment: Is there an issue with storing **all** of the data? Is there some kind of storage limit?

Comment: @ardavis contemporary devices have several gigabytes of memory, and this should not be a problem. if you want to target old devices, you might consider saving large portions of your data to external storage (SD card), optionally encrypting saved data, because external storage does not offer any access protection from other applications.

Answer (score 1):

While storing all (relevant) data locally is one option, it can get really huge at times and if your application booms then so will the space required. Instead keeping the latest copy of relevant data locally, and broadcasting an update which can be downloaded by your app if online is another way out.

Given your app is a social-network of sorts, you'll want the latest updates reaching users as soon as they're available. Storing locally and firing an async-task at intervals would mean you're fixing the delay in updates (which would equal the delay between async task runs + running time of the task). Additionally, many times it would be possible that there was no update, and you'd be pointlessly querying the server.

This can be combated with the "broadcast updates" approach, where your server stores a list of devices being served (which could be registered at app installation time), and every time there is an update relevant to a certain set of devices you could broadcast the update to 'em. (Try [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html) for a start on this approach.)